# What's the Practicum in Advance Alchemy quest reward?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I just finished helping Gremist and he took me as his apprentice and finished the quest, but I don't understand what my reward was from this quest, also could not find it anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reward for this quest, according to the [GosuNoob](http://www.gosunoob.com/witcher-3/practicum-in-advanced-alchemy/) database, is:

- 5x Sulfur
- 5x Alcohest
- 5x Han Fiber
- 5x Saltpetre

This will probably be in your alchemy tab in your inventory - but as you've likely already got at least one of each of those, it might not have been immediately obvious.

In addition, as mentioned by Mad Scientist, it unlocks Gremist as an alchemy vendor, which is important if you have any use for oils/potions/bombs.

Comment: It is important to note that he sells Rebis, a component in many superior recipes, even ones looted normally. You cannot exploit Alchemy to its fullest without having done the quest and bought the recipe.

Comment: Is he the only vendor who sells Rebis? I seem to remember getting it somewhere else at some point (possibly The Pellar?)

Comment: As far as I know, completing the quest is the only way to get Rebis. I also believe he is the only vendor. It is supposed to be rare.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/36q3bt/anyone_found_any_rebis/ Seems like it might be a rare loot item, as well as the Prima guide apparently listing it on various vendors (though they didn't have it according to the comment). Just a brief Google, though.

Comment: Yolar, the herbalist below the big tree near Gremist sell the exact same diagrams. So the only real reward is being able to play him for his Gwent card.

Answer (score 4):

I think you get some alchemy ingredients as a reward, but that is actually not the important part. After finishing the quest you can buy alchemy recipes from him, which is far more important. The improved and superior versions of potions and bombs are very powerful, access to more recipes is the actual reward.